# How can I see if a user is logged in with Authomatic?

Tags: python, flask, authomatic

I'm writing a small Flask app and I'd like to use Authomatic to handle OAuth and OpenID authentication. Is there a way to decorate a function to check if a user is logged in or not, as it would be done with Flask-Login? Or should I use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use both. Authomatic provides a method for authenticate users, while Flask-Login takes care of user sessions. Have a look at [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) as well, it's a complete package for user management (Flask-Login itself does not give you database models for registering users).